# I am unable to change language to French ion2-calendar

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

bonjour

i'm using ion2-calendar from https://www.npmjs.com/package/ion2-calendar

i'm wondering if i can change language of days in months to French,

https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/6/13/c39d2b57b8cbae7bbb2f83c60c780512-full.png

Comment: Have you seen this: https://github.com/HsuanXyz/ion2-calendar#localization ?

Answer (score 2):

have you solved?

If you use components mode, 
1. add options in the html,

```
<ion-calendar [(ngModel)]="dateRange"
      [options]="options" <!-- this one -->
      [type]="type"
      [format]="'YYYY-MM-DD'">
</ion-calendar>
```

2.then import 'CalendarComponentOptions' in ts file

```
import { CalendarComponentOptions } from 'ion2-calendar'
```

3.then put following options in ts file

```
  dateMulti: string[];
  type: 'string'; // 'string' | 'js-date' | 'moment' | 'time' | 'object'
  options: CalendarComponentOptions = {
  monthPickerFormat: ['janvier','février','mars','avril ,mai','juin','juillet','août','septembre','octobre','novembre',décembre'],
  weekdays: ['lundi','mardi','mercredi','jeudi','vendredi','samedi','dimanche']
  };
```

Oh,, maybe I misunderstood.
The month you pointed out, I am not sure how to change.
Maybe you can only change the options like below

```
monthFormat: 'MM/YYYY',
```